# How to get Solr result as per their scores

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4, solrnet

I am working on Solr with ASP.Net MVC.

**I want to display result as per score result**. It means if I search for any keyword, it gives me total 500 result. But I want only first 100 Results. I also display scores for results using following query:

```
Fields = new[] {"*","score"},
```

**I want results which have score more than 0.3**

How can I do this in Solr? Also a solrnet query to get this result.

Please advise.
Thank you.

Comment: Bad idea, see https://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ScoresAsPercentages

Comment: If you want the first 100 results, just grab the first 100 results with pagination, see https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Querying.md#pagination

Comment: Thank you Mauricio. But, actually I don't want to show irrelevant results. So, if I set score to 0.3 I want results which have score 0.3 or more. How can I do this in solr? Please advice.

Comment: That's not the way to go. See https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ