# Remove search results with lower score than specified value in Solr

Tags: solr, solr4, solrnet

On a very large volume of index, for most of the query I am getting search results in lacs number of features.

So I want to display search results that are more than certain specified score value, and not all the results.

How to remove results with lower score than specified value in solr?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26842830/how-to-get-solr-result-as-per-their-scores

Comment: @mauricioScheffer Thanks for the link, its useful. But doen't address the issue I am facing. Can you give me a hint that is more useful?

Comment: Have you seen all the links I posted on that question? It's the same question really.